# Setting a sheet to be hidden. Code won't work

Tags: vba, excel, hide, visible

I have the following code in on a workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Main Page" Then
       ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next ws

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

But when the workbook is next open pages that were left open at the end are still open. I don't have any other macro's or vba script that sets the pages to be unhidden yet, I'm am just doing to manually to test it.

There are no errors that come up, the code complies correctly and runs. I even check the loop with breakpoints and it does go through every worksheet correctly.

Can anyone see what might be the problem? Have I missed one vital key word or something? Its driving me nuts, worse than trying to track down ; in c#

Ask any questions you think would help.

Matt

Comment: The code is fine, something else that is messing it up. Are you trying to hide Main Page? or everything else? Your code hides everything else.  Are you sure you are inside the correct workbook when code is running?

Comment: Yep. I got it working now by moving the exact code from the Workbook_BeforeClose event to a cmdButton event and it works. One to think about.

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like

```
ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

Comment: Nope still there, and still very visible

Answer (score 0):

Check if the workbook is protected.  If it's protected, you have to unprotect the workbook first.

Comment: Nope. No protection. The code works fine when its attached to a button but some some reason it just doesn't work on the BeforeClose event.